# First argument cannot contain nil or be empty rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm making a single page application based on Futureme.org for practice. The user goes to the home page, sees a form to put their email address, subject, and the body of their message and sends it.

The problem I am having is I get an error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". Here is my code;

Model;

```
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-,]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates_presence_of :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                          uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    validates_length_of :subject, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

    validates_presence_of :message


end
```

Controller;

```
class LettersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @letter = Letter.new
    end

    def create
        @letter = Letter.new(params[:letter])

        if @letter.save
            redirect_to letters_path, :notice => "Your letter was sent!"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

end
```

View form;

```
 <%= form_for @letter, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
     <% if @letter.errors.any? %>
       <div class="error_messages">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@letter.errors.count, "error")%>stopped this message from being saved</h2>

       <ul>
       <% @letter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>  
        <% end %>
      </ul>

    <% end %>  






  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :subject %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :subject %><br />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :message, "Message" %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :message, size: "60x10" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %></div>

  <% end %>
```

The form is on the home page which is in the "Welcome Controller".

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you build letter in action `new` when form is drawn on other view :)

You should move `@letter = Letter.new` to appropriate action

One of the variant is:

```
#WelcomeController
def home
  @letter = Letter.new
end

#LettersController
def create
  @letter = Letter.new(params[:letter])
  if @letter.save
    redirect_to letters_path, :notice => "Your letter was sent!"
  else
    render "welcome/home"
  end
end
```

be careful if you prepare some data in action `home` you should care about initializing them for action `create` when validation failed because you render "welcome/home" view

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you clarify what you mean by move it to the appropriate action? I tried moving the "new" action to the Welcome controller instead of the Letters controller but it still doesn't work